# Custom Post Type order Title ASC

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy, page-template

I´d like to display all car manufacturer in order by title (e.g. "Merecedes") and order from lowest to highest values (e.g. "A-Class") "ASC", too. It should looks like a glossary.

#### Page: Cars

A
...

BMW:
1er
2er
3er
...

Mercedes:
A-Class
B-Class
C-Class
...

Z

This is my `custom-port-type-cars.php`

```
<h2>Mercedes</h2>
    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'cars', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 

    // ============================= Mercedes ==============================
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'manufacturer',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('mercedes')
            )
        )
    );

    // ============================= OUTPUT ==============================
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        the_title('<h3>', '</h3>');
        the_content();
    endwhile; ?>


<h2>BMW</h2> 
    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'cars', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 

    // ============================= BMW ==============================
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'manufacturer',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('bmw')
            )
        )
    );


    // ============================= OUTPUT ==============================
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        the_title('<h3>', '</h3>');
        the_content();
    endwhile; ?>
```

This doesn´t work for me. I can´t order title an terms at the same time.

Thanks for your help
Ogni

Comment: You forgot the question.

Comment: So you are ordering manually by terms and with WP_Query by titles. Where does it go wrong? Any example of output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$index = 'A';
$terms = get_terms('manufacturer');

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    if($index != strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1))) {
        $index = strtoupper(substr($term->name, 0, 1));
        echo '<h1>'. $index . '</h1>';
    }
    ?>
    <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'cars', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'manufacturer',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array($term->slug)
            )
        )
    );

    // ============================= OUTPUT ==============================
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        the_title('<h3>', '</h3>');
        the_content();
    endwhile;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can I add a glossary index-nav like "A", "B BMW", "C", ... "M Mercedes", too?

Comment: edited the answer